# Remove a parent branch in Bazaar

Tags: bazaar

Given the following scenario:

```
$ bzr init-repo foo
$ bzr init foo/bar
$ cd foo/bar
$ echo 'some text' > a_file
$ bzr add a_file 
$ bzr commit -m 'a commit message' 
$ cd ..
$ bzr branch bar trunk
$ bzr rmbranch bar
bzr: ERROR: Branch is active. Use --force to remove it.
```

Is it safe to do a `bzr rmbranch --force` in this situation? Isn't there a more elegant solution?

After doing a `bzr rmbranch --force`, `bzr info` still shows `../foo/bar` as the parent branch of `trunk`, how can I change that?

Comment: I've repeated your steps and wasn't able to reproduce your problem, i.e. I didn't get this error. What is your bzr version?

Comment: @bialix I repeated the steps and I do get the error. Using Bazaar (bzr) 2.7.0dev1, /usr/bin/python 2.7.6, on Linux-3.13.0-24-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty, if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bzr rmbranch` simply removes branch at the given location. It's very handy if you need to delete a branch on your server.

On your local disk it's fine to just use `rm` or `del` command (depending on your OS/shell) if you want to delete some branch and tree.

NOTE: `rmbranch` does not delete the tree if one is present, just branch object. (And in your example working tree is actually present). For local workspace it's much simpler to use `rm`.

Parent branch is recorded in `.bzr/branch/branch.conf`. You can edit that config file. It doesn't affect branch deleting.

Comment: Do you know if a forced remove of a branch is safe?

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming local, "standalone" bzr shared repository.)

Interesting bzr commands used: `bzr init-repo`, `bzr init`, `bzr branch`, `bzr info`,  `bzr add`, `bzr commit`, `bzr remove-tree`, `bzr remove-branch`.

### Setup a single branch in a shared repository

Set up a shared repo in your `/tmp` directory to play with.

```
$ cd /tmp/
$ bzr init-repo test-shared-repo
$ bzr info test-shared-repo/
```

yields:

```
Shared repository with trees (format: 2a)
Location:
  shared repository: test-shared-repo
```

Then we create a place to store some code in that shared repo:

```
$ bzr init test-shared-repo/first
```

yields the following, which means that "first" is using the shared repo we created above (and it also happens to be stored there):

```
Using shared repository: /tmp/test-shared-repo/
```

And we go into the shared repo dir and get info on the shared repo:

```
$ cd test-shared-repo
$ bzr info
```

Which yields the following, which restates what was given when we created it:

```
Shared repository with trees (format: 2a)
Location:
  shared repository: .
```

Let's also check the info on the "first" thing we created:

```
$ bzr info first/
```

Yields the following which shows that "first" is a repository branch that uses a shared repository located at `.`:

```
Repository tree (format: 2a)
Location:
  shared repository: .
  repository branch: first
```

### Add code to the first and branch a second from it

Let's create, add, and commit some "code" to our "first" branch, then back out to the shared repo:

```
$ cd first/
$ echo "some text" > a_file.txt
$ bzr add a_file.txt
$ bzr commit -m 'a commit message' 
$ cd ..
```

Now branch from "first" to "second":

```
$ bzr branch first second
```

Yields the following, which shows that "second" has a reference to "first":

```
Repository tree (format: 2a)
Location:
  shared repository: .
  repository branch: second

Related branches:
  parent branch: first
```

If you check `bzr info first`, you can confirm that there is no reference to "second", however. Confirm there is some stuff in "second":

```
$ ls second
a_file.txt
```

### Deleting one of the branches

Let's say we're done with either "first" or "second" because we've finished a bug fix, etc. Problem is that we cannot use "bzr remove-branch" on *either* of them at the moment:

```
$ bzr remove-branch first
bzr: ERROR: Branch is active. Use --force to remove it.
$ bzr remove-branch second
bzr: ERROR: Branch is active. Use --force to remove it.
```

I discovered something called `bzr remove-tree`, however, that seems to do the trick. It will *obliterate* the contents (I think if there are no uncommitted changes), so be careful!

```
$ bzr remove-tree second
$ ls -a second
.  ..  .bzr
```

Files are gone in "second". But there is still some reference to the "first":

```
$ bzr info second
Repository branch (format: 2a)
Location:
  shared repository: .
  repository branch: second

Related branches:
  parent branch: first
```

So, let's now try `bzr remove-branch` on "second":

```
$ bzr remove-branch second
$ bzr info second
Empty control directory (format: 2a or pack-0.92)
Location:
  control directory: second
```

It seems like everything in "second" is gone and I could then safely trash (`rm` / `del`) the "second" directory.

(Others, please edit this to provide more info on the proper method of removing a branch in a shared repository.)